# Java - process image while reading it

Tags: java, multithreading, image, image-processing

I'm designing a server-side application that takes an image from a user, processes it, and sends it back over the network. Since the network connection might be quite slow, I'd like to speed things up by starting to process parts of the image while it is still being sent over the network and send parts of the processed image back to the client while other parts are still being processed.

Is this possible, preferably using the [`javax.imageio`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) classes?

EDIT: I am mostly interested in *writing* `PNG`files. Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Critical_chunks): "*IDAT contains the image, which may be split among multiple IDAT chunks. Doing so increases filesize slightly, but makes it possible to generate a PNG in a streaming manner.*"

Comment: that entirely depends on what the processing entails...

Comment: You can resize the image before uploading with javascript. Plupload has this feature.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Well, I know my processing would work without me having access to the entire image at once, so that's no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This strongly depends on the encoding of the image.  Some image formats require the whole file to be available before you can decode it.  Others - like GIF and some PNG encodings (as far as I remember) decode to indvidual blocks which can then be processed.

You most likely need to write custom decoders, which may be quite a bit of work if you are not intimately familiar with the formats, and you need to support several.

I think you perhaps should work on an upload bar instead?

Comment: As far as I know I will only need support for PNG encoding. How about if I want to _write_ the image, do I have to have the entire image to start writing it to disk?

Comment: Depends on your encoding.  I would suggest you study the format closer to see what you can do and not do:  http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/